# Return multicast observable from switchmap

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have some problem trying to understand why do I need to pipe `share` operator at the outer observable when trying to make shared observable. I would think that it will be sufficient to pass `share` as part of observable returned inside `switchMap`, but it looks like it is not the case.

```js
const {
  catchError,
  concatMap,
  count,
  debounceTime,
  delay,
  finalize,
  map,
  mapTo,
  mergeMap,
  startWith,
  switchMap,
  tap,
  take,
  toArray,
  takeUntil,
  bufferTime,
  filter,
  bufferWhen,
  share,
  distinctUntilChanged,
} = rxjs.operators;
const {
  fromEventPattern,
  BehaviorSubject,
  Subject,
  of,
  timer,
  interval,
} = rxjs;

const first = new BehaviorSubject(1);
const destroy = new Subject();
const first$ = first.asObservable().pipe(
  map((value) => parseInt(value, 10)),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  takeUntil(destroy)
);

const createInterval = () =>
  interval(1000).pipe(
    finalize(() => console.log('finalize')),
    share() // here I create multicast observable
  );

const events$ = first$.pipe(
  share(),
  switchMap(() => createInterval())
  //share() // why this is needed outside and the `share` above is not sufficient ?
);

events$
  .pipe(tap((value) => console.log('first', value)))
  .subscribe((value) => console.log('subscription 1', value));

// not subscribing properly without share() above
events$
  .pipe(tap((value) => console.log('second', value)))
  .subscribe((value) => console.log('subscription 2', value));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@^7/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/share) its says:

> Returns a new Observable that multicasts (shares) the original
> Observable. As long as there is at least one Subscriber this
> Observable will be subscribed and emitting data. When all subscribers
> have unsubscribed it will unsubscribe from the source Observable.
> Because the Observable is multicasting it makes the stream hot. This
> is an alias for multicast(() => new Subject()), refCount().

So we can share the output stream observable to multiple subscribers, without creating new streams!

To demo this, here I have a code, where there is no share, but a tap above the switchMap, to indicate the interval is getting executed on each subscription! The first subscribe happens immediately, but the second happens after 3 seconds, you will see there are two streams here, so in the context of an API, one which is static, we can use share to reduce the number of calls, this is just an example!

```js
const {
  catchError,
  concatMap,
  count,
  debounceTime,
  delay,
  finalize,
  map,
  mapTo,
  mergeMap,
  startWith,
  switchMap,
  tap,
  take,
  toArray,
  takeUntil,
  bufferTime,
  filter,
  bufferWhen,
  share,
  distinctUntilChanged,
} = rxjs.operators;
const {
  fromEventPattern,
  BehaviorSubject,
  Subject,
  of ,
  timer,
  interval,
} = rxjs;

const first = new BehaviorSubject(1);
const destroy = new Subject();
const first$ = first.asObservable().pipe(
  map((value) => parseInt(value, 10)),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  takeUntil(destroy)
);

const createInterval = () =>
  interval(1000).pipe(
    finalize(() => console.log('finalize')),
  );

const events$ = first$.pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('calling')),
  switchMap(() => createInterval()),
  //share() // why this is needed outside and the `share` above is not sufficient ?
);

events$
  .pipe(tap((value) => console.log('first', value)))
  .subscribe((value) => console.log('subscription 1', value));

setTimeout(() => {
  // not subscribing properly without share() above
  events$
    .pipe(tap((value) => console.log('second', value)))
    .subscribe((value) => console.log('subscription 2', value));

}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@^7/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

We do not need multiple shares, because the code above it will be shared, in your case, what I think happened was **you are sharing the behavioursubject part (upto the stream above the share!) with two subscribers, since you have distinct until unchanged here, the first subscriber gets subscribed, since the value has changed, but the second does not because it has the same value in the stream!**

The fix for this will be to have a single share, either in the inner observable `createInterval` or on `events$` (as the last pipe operator).

Finally here is a working example, where it works fine!

```js
const {
  catchError,
  concatMap,
  count,
  debounceTime,
  delay,
  finalize,
  map,
  mapTo,
  mergeMap,
  startWith,
  switchMap,
  tap,
  take,
  toArray,
  takeUntil,
  bufferTime,
  filter,
  bufferWhen,
  share,
  distinctUntilChanged,
} = rxjs.operators;
const {
  fromEventPattern,
  BehaviorSubject,
  Subject,
  of ,
  timer,
  interval,
} = rxjs;

const first = new BehaviorSubject(1);
const destroy = new Subject();
const first$ = first.asObservable().pipe(
  map((value) => parseInt(value, 10)),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  takeUntil(destroy)
);

const createInterval = () =>
  interval(1000).pipe(
    finalize(() => console.log('finalize')),
    // share(),
  );

const events$ = first$.pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('calling')),
  switchMap(() => createInterval()),
  share(),
);

events$
  .pipe(tap((value) => console.log('first', value)))
  .subscribe((value) => console.log('subscription 1', value));

// not subscribing properly without share() above
events$
  .pipe(tap((value) => console.log('second', value)))
  .subscribe((value) => console.log('subscription 2', value));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@^7/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The case here is that I'd want to subscribe to stream which listens on `first` stream, then switches to some service which emits events, and then share the events stream with allowing for multiple subscriptions. But for each emit of `first` stream I want to have exacly 1 instance of this service and upon `first` changes I'd like to cleanup service (using finalize). The second example you provided seem to properly handle this case triggering `calling` only once.

Comment: @Maksym So your question is clarified right?